Dovecot fails login with username@domain.com, only direct username works
A login to dovecot only works with the defined username in the /home/ directory.
I've already tried auth_username_format = %n and auth_username_format=%{if;%d;eq;my-fqdn-hostname;%Ln;%Lu}, both with no success.
Furthermore, I as well tried the here described step, as well without any success. I used alias@user:::::::user=real_username noauthenticate instead.
